# how to prove that a function has a fixed point.

Tags: continuity

ok , my question is how to prove that this function $$f(x)= \frac{7}{2} x(1-x)$$ has one and only one fixed point in $I=]0,1[.$

thank you for helping me. and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Hint: You need to show there is an $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x.$

Comment: yeah i know, but how to do that. usually i just use this g(x)=f(x)-x and show that g(x) = 0. but ...

Comment: Note that $f(x)-x=0$ is a quadratic equation in $x.$ How would you solve a quadratic equation ?

Comment: ohhhhh, i see now..... well thank you for your help i rally appreciate it.

Comment: You can as well use that $\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$ when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: thaaank youuuuu!

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = x \iff \\
\frac{7}{2} x (1-x) = x
$$
we want solutions $x \in I$, so $x \ne 0$ and we can divide both sides by $x$:
$$
\frac{7}{2} (1-x) = 1 \iff \\
1 - x = \frac{2}{7} \iff \\
x = 1 - \frac{2}{7} = \frac{5}{7} \in I
$$